# Is it possible for someone at home to verify with their own (single P.C.) equipment the primality of the largest known prime numbers?

Tags: math, distributed-computing, prime-factoring

If one had the software to check, would the program be able to complete in a reasonable amount of time, or at all? What software is necessary? Are multiple P.C.'s necessary for checking just one number?

Answer (score 2):

Let's quote an article about the most recently discovered large prime 2<sup>74,207,281</sup> - 1.
https://www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M74207281

> The primality proof took 31 days of non-stop computing on a PC with an Intel I7-4790 CPU.  To prove there were no errors in the prime discovery process, the new prime was independently verified using both different software and hardware. Andreas Hoglund and David Stanfill each verified the prime using the CUDALucas software running on NVidia Titan Black GPUs in 2.3 days. David Stanfill verified it using ClLucas on an AMD Fury X GPU in 3.5 days. Serge Batalov also verified it using Ernst Mayer's MLucas software on two Intel Xeon 18-core Amazon EC2 servers in 3.5 days.

So anywhere from 3 days to a month depending on how much hardware you put in a single computer.

Comment: CUDAlucas software is to test for Mersenne Primes, not primes in general.

Comment: @user7778287: True, but you asked about "the largest known prime numbers," and thanks to the Lucas test they are all Mersenne primes. Other known prime numbers are much smaller.

Comment: Well, the seventh largest known prime isn't a mersenne, but I mostly agree.